# After plugin update the pluginfolder is renamed

Tags: wordpress

When updating a Wordpress plugin, which is hosted outside the wp-repository, the plugin folder gets renamed and 6 characters are added.
For example "ma-favorite-plugin" is renamed to "my-favorite-plugin-wD7aLW".

Why does this happen?

Comment: I know this is an old post, but did you found a solution to this issue? Got the same thing…

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me when the structure of my zip file was like that:

```
my-plugin.php
/includes
  file1.php
  file2.php
```

The root directory should be included in the zip file, and then everything works fine.

```
/my-plugin
  my-plugin.php
  /includes
    file1.php
    file2.php
```

Comment: 100%, same fix: has to make sure the zip unzipped with a top level directory. I thought there was a top level folder in the zip but that was my local unzipper making a folder on creation.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say it's a strange thing. I often work with plugins outside the standard repository.

have you checked that the files in the folder are the original ones and that there hasn't been any hack a plugin itself or on your site?

Check the files and try another plugin, then check on [https://sitecheck.sucuri.net/](https://sitecheck.sucuri.net)

Comment: All files are OK. This happened on a development installation, not on a active website. We are testing a plugin there with update function for extern hosted files.